# How do I set the name of a variable from a function's argument?

Tags: python

So my problem is I want to define the name of a variable off of a function's argument.
I can do it outside of a function as two variables:

```
name = "test"
vars()[str(name)] = 2
print(test)
```

and this will give me an output of `2`, which is what I was looking for.
However, as soon as I convert it into a function, It doesn't work:

```
def func(name):
    vars()[str(name)] = 2
    print(test)

func("test")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\---\Documents\Manim\Practice Presentation\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    func("test")
  File "C:\Users\---\Documents\Manim\Practice Presentation\test.py", line 3, in func
    print(test)
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

Is it possible to name a variable from an argument in a function? If not, is there another way that essentially does the same thing?
I'm not very experienced in python so a simple solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't. If the name matters, use an explicit `dict`.

Comment: May I ask you why do you want to do that?

Comment: The only way you can use `print(test)` is if you know that the value of `name` was `"test'`. If you know that, why use a variable in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesnt allow modification of locals() or vars() within the function.. you can update the globals() though.

```
def func(name):
    globals()[str(name)] = 2
    print(test)

func("test")
```

Comment: Don't do this either. Use a `dict` if the name matter.